# Words for breathing

Tags: usage

When does one use inspirer or expirer vs inhaler or exhaler?  Is the former related to normal respiration and the latter related, for example...to intake of medicine and emission of harmful substances?

Comment: The big picture is that "inspirer/expirer" is related to air, whilst "inhaler/exhaler" corresponds to something different (smoke, fumes, ...).

Answer (score 5):

To describe breathing, you would use "inspirer" for the inhalation and "expirer" for the exhalation. For example, a yoga coach could give such instructions:

> Levez le bras, puis inspirez. Retenez votre respiration pendant une seconde, et expirez. (Raise your hand, then inhale. Hold your breath for one second, and exhale.)

"Inhaler" and "exhaler" are usually related to stuff coming respectively in and out your lungs that is not normal air to breathe. For example you would say "inhaler" for "taking a medication through inhalation" or for "breathing in toxic fumes", or even figuratively.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about these verbs however *exhaler* is less likely to refer to something leaving your lungs but more likely to some fragrance/smell escaping from something like a flower, perfume, etc. and rarely harmful substances.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike *inspirer/expirer*, *inhaler* and *exhaler* are always transitive.

Since we deem it important to specify what is inhaled/exhaled, they are usually related to something else than normal air (not necessarily harmful substances though).

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exhaler

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/inhaler/43099